# How to access (PortalSiteMapNode) RootNode outside the SiteMapProvider?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation, sitemapprovider, root-node

A very simple question for experienced sharepoint developers I think.

Inside a PortalSiteMapProvider I can access the RootNode this way:

```
 (PortalSiteMapNode) RootNode
```

My Question is, how can I access this node from other places, without a reference to the provider? Is there something like

```
 SPContext.Current.Web.RootNode (just an example, this doesnt work)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to achieve, however, you cannot access any nodes of a site map provider without referencing that provider. A simple reason for this is that the sitemap may have a totally different structure to that of your SharePoint site collection.